# What are the different countries whose magical heritage is shown in "Constantine"?

Tags: dc, magic, arrowverse, constantine-2014

In the TV series *Constantine*, the titular character uses the magic of different religions and regions. Many different types of magic are used as [given here](https://constantine.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_Magic). Many ancient artifacts are used like *sinew from Achilles' heel, the ring of Solomon, Icon of Pazuzu, etc.* So what are the different countries whose magic is used by him?

Comment: Ultimately none of them are the best in the terms your thinking of because if one was then that would be the one Constantine uses exclusively.

As an aside I am not %100 certain about magic in that universe however its probable that the language and such do not actually matter, Magic is a universal force its more about reciting a spell in Arabic is easier than trying translate the spell exactly into English.

Comment: Is it about artifacts _and_ spells? Like where the spells originated? Also, that list might be out of date - it doesn't have the Icon of Pazuzu, for instance. If you've got another one more complete that answerers can use as the "list" to tackle, that'd probable be a nice thing to have :)

Comment: @jenayah yes its about the artifacts and spells that where they have originated

Comment: You can suggest the new list to answer the question I have been able to get only this list from fandom page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The magic shown in Constantine mostly, although not entirely, derives from real-world  beliefs about magic and religion, although some spells, such as the sleep spell, are not clearly tied to any tradition. Although most of it derives from European traditions, some comes from Africa or the Middle East, or occasionally Asia or South America.

Among the countries whose magic appears on the show, and in Constantine's follow-up appearances on other shows in the same cinematic universe after Constantine was folded into the Arrowverse, are:

- **West Africa**: [Voodoo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_African_Vodun). [Papa Midnite](https://constantine.fandom.com/wiki/Papa_Midnite/TV_Series) is a voodoo priest in the TV series. With a variety of spellings, Voudon refers to a set of religions and accompanying magical practices originally deriving from West African countries such as Benin and Nigeria. The form that Papa Midnite practices in the show may be more specifically from other regions, such as the state of Louisiana in the United States.
- **Greece**: Although I can't find a reference on the wiki, if the Heel of Achilles appears it would definitely be Greek. Also, as mentioned in other answers, [pentagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagram) had a symbolic significance in ancient Greece. Their use on Constantine may owe more to a generic association with Paganism and Wicca in the US and Europe than their original ancient Greek uses, however. The appearance of magic associated with the five classical elements is also a nod to Greek philosophy and mysticism.
- **Babylonia**: The demon or god [Pazuzu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pazuzu) appears on the show as an enemy of Constantine. His name was used in [protective amulets](https://arrow.fandom.com/wiki/Icon_of_Pazuzu) in ancient Mesopotamia generally. His enemy Lamashtu also appears later on. Pentagram magic was also practiced in ancient Babylonia, as was [capnomancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capnomancy); this latter was also practiced in Greece.
- **Israel/Judah/Palestine/Canaan**: The water of the Jordan harms evil beings, similar to holy water. The magic and cosmology of the series in general is also based heavily on Christianity, a religion originally founded in Israel: for instance, the presence of angels, demons, specific named demons such as Mammon or named angels such as Gabriel, Hell, and so forth. The Ring of [Solomon](https://arrow.fandom.com/wiki/Ring_of_Solomon) is another example.
- **Europe**: The [hand of glory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand_of_Glory) was believed in Europe to have powers capable of aiding a thief. I can't find a reference for the Grail being on the show, but it would also fit here. Obviously a Faustian bargain, named after Doctor Faustus, would also come from Europe. There are likely many other forms of magic in the series that come from Europe.
- **Wales**: The [coblynau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coblynau), although the  version in the show might draw inspiration from the Cornish knockers or the German kobolds.
- **Britain**: Apparently, Constantine knows an old Brittonic spell to allow resurrection.
- **Egypt:** The Eye of Horus, clearly.
- **Chile**: The [Brujeria](https://arrow.fandom.com/wiki/Brujeria) practiced some ancient form of magic originating in what is now Chile.
- **Turkey**: The demon [Karabasan](https://arrow.fandom.com/wiki/Karabasan) comes from Turkish lore.
- **Tibet**: Constantine used the [phurba](https://arrow.fandom.com/wiki/Phurba), a Tibetan ceremonial dagger, for certain ritual purposes.
- **United States**: Constantine has a magical gun, the [Ace of Winchester](https://arrow.fandom.com/wiki/Ace_of_Winchester), which draws on myths and folklore associated with the old [Winchester Repeating Arms Company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winchester_Repeating_Arms_Company) and its guns.

Answer (score 1):

Well, just going off [the list you gave](https://constantine.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_Magic), which doesn't include anything about Achilles (Greek legend), Solomon (Hebrew legend), or Pazuzu (Babylonian myth), you've got

- **Babylonia:** capnomancy, exorcism
- **Christendom:** Faust, grail, hand of glory
- **Egypt:** Eye of Horus
- **Greece:**

  - **Neoplatonism:** pentagrams
  - **Pythagoreanism:** pentagrams
- **Israel:** water of the Jordan
- **Wales:** coblynau (but here credited to the Romani for no apparent reason)

It's all just standard fare Western magic + a bit of peasant folklore. Every country around the world has attempted to understand and control nature through mistaken ideas about supposed connections/correlations and imagined causes and effects. The most important for learned Western men have been Greece, Egypt, and Babylonia as interpreted through Jewish and Christian theology; you still get pieces of that in things like Freemasonry. You also have a parallel strain of peasant magic that's more focused on nature, herbs, and local traditions; witches (i.e. local wise women) have usually drawn from that. From your list, it seems like *Constantine* is squarely in those two camps and hasn't bothered as much with voodoo, santaria, and eastern traditions in India,  China, &c.

Comment: "Every country around the world has attempted to understand and control nature through *mistaken ideas* about supposed connections/correlations and *imagined* causes and effects." This little bit of criticism seems tangential and I'm not sure it adds much to the answer.

Comment: @Adamant If you think magic is real, I don't know what else to tell you. Do some peer-reviewed research and make your name immortal. Or, yknow, accept that it's all hokum and misunderstood chemistry and always has been.

Comment: I think you're really missing the point. It's not that I believe magic is real, it's that this is a pointless bit of editorializing about things that various people *do* believe in an answer about *Constantine*. It would be like, if someone asked whether Superman was Labour or Conservative or UKIP or whatnot, going on a digression about how Superman clearly has the most affinity with the *mistaken ideas* of Labour.

Comment: Superman is an American immigrant and people's mistaken ideas about politics might be relevant to a question about supposed affiliation, so your explanation makes even less sense than your original complaint. If you have a better answer of your own, post it.

Comment: I wouldn't say your answer is *wrong*, it just contains a bit of what I consider unhelpful commentary. If I wrote an answer, it would just recapitulate what you wrote, in large part.

Comment: Still, I'll give it a try.